# Linq query problem

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following information

```
var details = Details.Where(d => d.isActive);
```

I would like to query another table, `Authorizations`, that has a FK to `Details`, and get the sum amounts of the authorizations that are contained within the `details` object grouped by the `detail` and a `FundCode`.

> Details (1 to many) Authorizations

Seems simple enough, however I'm having a bit of trouble.

Here is what I currently have:

```
var account = (from sumOfAuths in Authorizations
               where details.Contains(sumOfAuths.Details)
                     && sumOfAuths.RequestStatusId == 2
               group sumOfAuths by new { sumOfAuths.Detail, sumOfAuths.FundCode } into child
               select new { 
                ....
                Amount = child.Amount 
               }).Sum()
```

The problem is that inside the `.Sum()` function I have collection of objects rather than 1. So I can't Sum the amounts properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this query produces what you're looking for:

```
            var account = from c in Authorizations
                      where details.Contains(c.Details) && c.RequestStatusId == 2
                      group c by new { c.Detail, c.FundCode } into g
                      select new { Key = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Amount) };
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you can specify what it is you want to sum:

```
.Sum(x => x.Amount)
```

In groups, you can use nested sums:

```
.Sum(x => x.Sum(y => y.Amount));
```